# Highstock and multiple JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

.Hi, first, sorry for my english ;)

So, i need to put multiple JSON in my highstock. I use the "**basic line**" for the moment, can i put multiple lines in this one or i have to choose another highstock like [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)?... but i don't understand how it works.

My first data.js :

```
[[1362133360000,25],[1362136955000,14],[1362140579000,35],[1362144175000,21],[1362146967000,15],[1362150567000,16],[1362154351000,15],[1362157951000,12],[1362161559000,16],[1362164400000,11],[1362171600000,15],[1362174626000,18]]
```

My second data2.js :

```
[[1362133360000,12],[1362136955000,10],[1362140579000,30],[1362144175000,18],[1362146967000,10],[1362150567000,10],[1362154351000,10],[1362157951000,8],[1362161559000,11],[1362164400000,5],[1362171600000,10],[1362174626000,14]]
```

My highstocks works with one file, is [**like that**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyGyt/UVU3N/), so, i need to have 1 line for **data.json** and another one for **data2.json** .

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple series on a line chart.

```
series: [{
    name: 'series1',
    data: data1,
    },{
    name: 'series2',
    data: data2,
    }]
```

data1 would contain JSON from data.js, and data2 would contain JSON from data2.js.

So you could do something like this given your data structure:

```
$.getJSON('data.js', function (data1) {
    $.getJSON('data2.js', function (data2) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            series: [{
                    name: 'series1',
                    data: data1,
                }, {
                    name: 'series2',
                    data: data2,
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```